# Vue JS call function on v-model data() change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to call a function on data change through v-model

HTML Part:

```
<input
  type="date"
  name="date"
  id="date"
  v-model="inputDate"
  @change="recallMeetingDetails"
/>
```

VueJS Part:

```
data(){
  return(){
    inputDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
  }
}
methods: {
  recallMeetingDetails(){
    console.log(this.inputData);
  }
}
```

Now this code works fine, but in the console, I am getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

How can I do the functionality through any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find a solution, the issue was in a different function.

In data(), I had 2 variables, which I was altering in a different function.

```
data(){
  return{
    inputDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
    topValue: 0,
    heightValue: 78,
  }
}

fnWithIssue(x,y){
  this.topValue = x + this.topValue;
  this.heightValue = y + this.heightValue;

 return{
   top: `${topValue}px`,
   height: `${heightValue}px`,
 }
}
```

Then in a template, I was passing the aforementioned return as Inline styling, the template was in turn inside a v-for, which caused the infinite loop

Instead I was able to fix the issue by removing the data's topValue and heightValue and just decalred them in the fnWithIssue(x,y)

```
fnWithIssue(x,y){
  let topValue = x + topValue;
  let heightValue = y + heightValue;

  return{
    top: `${topValue}px`,
    height: `${heightValue}px`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using v-model is a great idea!

Use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to watch the reactive data instead of `@change` on the input element, and call a function when the reactive variable changes: [like this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
<input
  type="date"
  name="date"
  id="date"
  v-model="inputDate"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    inputDate(value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like following snippet :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      inputDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    recallMeetingDetails(date){
      this.inputDate = new Date(date).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input
    type="date"
    name="date"
    id="date"
    :value='inputDate'
    @input="recallMeetingDetails($event.target.value)"
  />
  <h3>{{ inputDate }}</h3>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

v-model watches for the value and updates it in data, try to use `v-bind:value="inputDate"` instead of v-model

Comment: The problem with v-bind:value was that on changing the input value, in <input type=data/>, it doesnt change the data value inputDate as well.
I need to change that value as well, coz  i am calling a function with this.inputDate which in turn calls an API

Comment: of course it wouldn't, but you can change it by yourself
`recallMeetingDetails(data){
    this.inputData = data
    console.log(this.inputData);
}
`

Comment: So on doing the changes as follows:
`v-bind:value="inputDate"
@change="recallMeetingDetails($event.target.value)"  `
and then in the recallMeetingDetails(data),  I am saving `this.inputData = data;`

However, Vue JS still gives me the warning, Is it case of Vue JS issue or theres a specific way do the changes

Comment: Wait is it a mispelling with `inputData`? i can't see it in your code

Comment: Yeah sorry its `inputDate`. I managed to get the solution. Will be answering it here in sometime.
Thanks for the help